# Why would you give me the same review audit twice?

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I just passed another review audit (yay) but it was quite easy because I noticed it was the same one I had already passed yesterday...

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1516065
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1524337

Should I be receiving the same audit multiple times, especially so close together in time?

Comment: Someone now needs to audit the audit...

Comment: The audit you get is random, so I don't think this is likely to happen very often

Comment: Just think though: how embarrassed would you have been if you'd failed it on the *second* try...

Comment: Juuuuuust to make sure.

Comment: Hey now you can decline your own bug report. How cool is that? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the (nonexhaustive list of) goals of review audits:

- making sure you're "paying attention"
- increasing review quality by nudging you in the direction of the community

I wouldn't call it a bug, since a duplicated review meets at least one of these goals. My vote: status-bydesign